# Can't display inline li elements

Tags: html, css

I try to display my li elements inline but result is likeon image: http://prntscr.com/87n6z8

Can anybody help me?

This is my html and css codes:

```
<footer>
        <ul class="footer_ul">
            <li><a href="#">O nama</a> |</li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a> |</li>
            <li><a href="#">Pitanja i odgovori</a> |</li>
            <li><a href="#">Video tutorijali</a> |</li>
            <li><a href="#">Pravila korištenja</a></li>
        </ul>
</footer>


footer{
    width:100%;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background:white;
}

.footer_ul{
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.footer_ul li{
    padding:5px;
}

.footer_ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome at SO! Instead of the screenshot (which did not show?) you could post your example on one of the services like jsfiddle or similar (cssfiddle?) where one can play with the actual code.

Comment: @Felix Thank you, I will remember that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to give it to `<LI>`. It has a default value of `display: list-item`. So change your code to:

```
.footer_ul li{
    padding:5px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: uh, how I overlooked it
Tanks

Comment: @CroVG Glad that it helped.